# Is it safe to use undefined variables in jquery for cross platform and future applications?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

Assuming the first two conditions are met in the first long `if` statement there are many possibilities where `$(this).val().split("@")[1].split(".")[1]` could be undefined. Is it safe to use this kind of technique with javascript/jquery?

```
        $("#confEmail").keyup(function()
        {
            if(!validId)
            {
                if($(this).val() == $("#email").val() && $(this).val().split("@")[1].split(".")[1] == "com")
                {
                    validEmail = true;
                    $("#emailIndicator").css("background-color","green");
                }
                else
                {
                    validEmail = false;
                    $("#emailIndicator").css("background-color","red");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: You really shouldn't, as there is no reason to do this. Just make a function which accepts an argument. There are a million better ways than just hoping that a global vaqriable is defined.

Comment: More to the point, overall that is not a very good way to tell whether an email is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use it.But you need to do code handling for undefined condition.It is safe but code must handle all the possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to javascript. You're chaining a bunch of functions/accessors where the result could be null or falsy. `split('@')` length may be < 1. The same for the second split. You should code defensively unless you explicitly know that those things will evaluate to what you expect, otherwise it will blow up in your face.